# Smack API can we listen to the subscription requests of all the users from XMPP?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack

- I have a collaboration product for which I am adding a chat feature
- I want to notify users (through email or some other means) whenever they get subscription requests
- How can I achieve it through smack? My understanding is that you have to login to XMPP server using your credentials and can register a listener for presence events of the logged in user.
- But what I want is to listen to all the presence subscription requests. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you will have to write a server side module for this kind of functionality.  The spec doesn't provide this ability so you would have to add it as a custom capability in the server.